# Automation for selecting dropdown items in the webpage

Tags: javascript, automation, applescript, selection, webautomation

I am trying to automate the process of filling the webpage which has lot of selection list.

can anyone suggest how to get start with it.
Can i use javascript.

Additional info:
Website is not hosted by me, third party site.

Regards
Su

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automate website regression testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731566/how-to-automate-website-regression-testing)

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how to select a menu item from a drop down list, go to this website: http://nzbindex.com. See the "Maximum age" drop down? If I wanted to select the first menu item under that (30 days), with the web page frontmost in Safari I can run the following. Of course you have to look at the html code of the web page to figure out the name of that drop down menu (in this case "age"). I hope that helps.

```
tell application "Safari"
   tell document 1
      do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"age\").selectedIndex = 1;"
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly fine for similar selection list.

 When this script is used for the form containing selection list whose selection will displayed in the text field, this script fails to add the selected item to the text field.

Comment: Third example(asmSelect) in this site http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/

Comment: I see what you mean and don't have a solution. Maybe some javascript expert can give you the code. My example would then guide you on how to use the javascript code in applescript. Good luck.